# How to "validate" a Rubik's Cube configuration?

Tags: rubiks-cube

Looking at a picture of a Rubik's cube how can I tell if it's in one of its possible configurations (image is not fake)? By "possible configuration" I mean a configuration that can be achieved by simply rotating the cube (no dismantling). I'm aware that colors of opposite sides cannot be on the same side and I'm interested in a more general solution.

Comment: Well, if you have physical access to the cube then you can solve it. There are algorithms that are guaranteed to solve a cube if it is solvable, and if it is not solvable you will reduce it to a state which is manifestly not solvable.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/127577).