# Rubiks Cube Corner Orientation

Tags: permutations, rubiks-cube

So, I've been studying the permutations of the $3\times3$ Rubik's Cube.

Wikipedia says that *Each corner has three possible orientations, although only seven (of eight) can be oriented independently; the orientation of the eighth (final) corner depends on the preceding seven.*

I understand this, but I do not understand how to predict the orientation of the eighth corner. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possible description (partially self-plagiarized from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127577/how-to-tell-if-a-rubiks-cube-is-solvable)):

Select two opposing colors, such as yellow and white on most cubes; call stickers of either of these two colors "fancy". Each corner cubie has exactly one fancy side.

Let's say that a corner is "oriented correctly" for its instant position if its fancy side is next to a fancy center. Now for any way to assemble the cube, consider how many *clockwise* 120° twists of a corner-in-place it would take to orient all of the corners "correctly" without moving them. If this number is a multiple of $3$, the configuration passes the corner orientation test. (It is easy to see that a quarter turn of face with a fancy center keeps this number unchanged, and only slightly more complex that a quarter turn of one of the four other faces changes it by a multiple of $3$).

To predict the last corner's orientation, therefore, count up how many third-twists are necessary to orient all the *other* corners "correctly". There will now be $0$, $1$ or $2$ twists left for the last corner.

Comment: I have prepared an example to your answer..

Answer (score 2):

This might help a little bit.  Take a solved Rubik's Cube.  For every clockwise rotation, on one of the corners, you have to make a counterclockwise rotation on a corner as well.

So If you know in which direction each of the 7 corners have been rotated, you can predict the last one.

For example:

Say I have three corners rotated counter clockwise, with three more rotated clockwise.  This means the final one has to be oriented correctly.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This, by itself, only works when all of the corner cubies are already in the right _place_. Otherwise it is not immediately clear how much it should count as having been rotated.

Answer (score 2):

This is an appendix to the Makholm's answer. It is, in fact, an example that I prepared for you.

Suppose our Rubik's cube is scrambled and we see only 7 corners. 4 top ones and 3 bottom ones. We name them $T1,T2,T3,T4$ and $B1,B2,B3$ respectively. Hidden will be called $B4.$ In our case the top is yellow and the bottom is white.

[image]

Let us, for fun, call yellow and white colors as **good** colors.

Now we play the following game. First to each visible corner we attach number 0,1 or 2:

- 0 if the **good** color is on top (resp. bottom)
- 1 if we need to twist corner clockwise to get **good** color on top (resp. bottom)
- 2 if we need to twist corner anticlockwise to get **good** color on top (resp. bottom)

In our situation we have: $T1-0;T2-2;T3-2;T4-1;B1-2;B2-1;B3-1.$ If you are not comfortable with colors on rubiks cube you have to believe me in $T4,B1$ and $B3.$

Next we add all this numbers modulo $3.$ $$X=0+2+2+1+2+1+1=9=0 \mod 3.$$

Our claim for $B4$ is following:

- if $X=0$ then **good** color is on bottom
- if $X=1$ then we need to twist corner anticlockwise to get **good** color on bottom
- if $X=2$ then we need to twist corner clockwise to get **good** color on bottom

Surprise!

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I actually figured it out on my own, but hey! We got the same thing!