# False Rubik Cube and math

Tags: rubiks-cube

imagine you are given an scrambled Rubik cube :D , how would you know that this cube has a solution ?

imagine i am a bad person and put the colors around the cube :d in a certain form that it has no solution how could you guess it ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127577/how-to-tell-if-a-rubiks-cube-is-solvable?rq=1

Comment: In the question @SassatelliGiulio gave there's a situation the cube is made from the proper Rubic's cube. So first we have to check what are the colours of the faces, then of the edges and of the corners (together with the orientation of corners) and then check if you have the proper elements. If yes, the cube can be made from these elements but maybe by dismantling it. Then we are in a position of the post Sallatelli reminded.

Comment: Your question is not entirely academic. My father used to peel the stickers off our cube and reposition them all the time. This was because he didn't know how to solve it and was trying to get in a position he thought he could handle. Alas, it was common to pick up the cube and find corners or edges with two stickers of the same color (sometimes even all three stickers on a corner would be the same). If I didn't find anything obvious like that, my technique was to attempt to solve it, until I would run into something impossible.